# Visits Time-of-day Histogram for last week in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How can I know the hours of a day in which my site is the busiest from Google Analytics?

I need the graph to take data from last week's visits and show the sum of visits for every hour of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with

```
Customisation > Custom Reports > New custom report
```

Then choose `Dimension = Hour`. This gives the desired result:

[image]

Note: this seems to be the hour-of-day **in your timezone** (Analytics account owner), and not the hours from the perspective of the different visitors around the world.

The latter is a different problem that I'm precisely searching a solution in [Hour of day of a pageview/event/purchase, but in the visitor's timezone?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132303/hour-of-day-of-a-pageview-event-purchase-but-in-the-visitors-timezone).

Answer (score 1):

1. Select last week's date range in the drop down box in the upper right hand corner of Google Analytics.
2. Click 'Audience' to the left on the toolbar and your visitors will show up by the 'day' measurement.
3. Finally, underneath the date range drop down you will see four buttons (hourly, day, week, month). Select the 'hourly' button and you should have a perfect view of visits by hour of the date range specified.

Here is an image of what your Google Analytics screen should look like with the applied changes. The buttons to click are highlighted in blue for you.

[image]

Hint: Drag the image to a new browser tab to view in full-size.