# Hour of day of a pageview/event/purchase, but in the visitor's timezone?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Note: this is totally different to [Visits Time-of-day Histogram for last week in Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49541/visits-time-of-day-histogram-for-last-week-in-google-analytics), for the reason explained below.

---

It's possible to view the "hour of day" of pageviews/events/transactions by doing:

- Customisation > Custom Reports > New custom report. Then I tried the three options Dimension = `Hour`, or `Hour of Day`, or `Hour index` (see screenshot below)
- But this shows the hour of the event from **my** local timezone! (I tested it for events that I know they happened around 10 pm GMT, and the segment involved only people with at least 6 hour difference from GMT. Still it was reported as hour = 10 pm)

**I'd like to know the hours-of-day when visitors visit the website, but with *their* timezone. How to do this?**

What for? Example: to answer this question: do people do a purchase transaction more on morning, midday, evening, night? (of course, with their timezone perspective).

How to do this with Google Analytics?

---

[image]

Comment: It looks like somebody asked this on Reddit and only got the answer that reports are all based on your own time zone.  [Time of Day Index, Hour dimensions - based on visitor's time zone or your time zone? : GoogleAnalytics](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAnalytics/comments/cgfe6k/time_of_day_index_hour_dimensions_based_on/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing @StephenOstermiller. This seems to be the answer, feel free to post it, with the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, this article [Add true user local time layer to Google Analytics data](https://dtlytics.com/2019/01/add-true-user-local-time-layer-to-google-analytics-data/) deals exactly with this question:

> Google Analytics reports on Account Level time (i.e. hour of day) and not User level time.

It then explains a few solutions to get the hour-of-data with client timezone (blue), rather than the GA account timezone (red).

[image]